# Where to put dispatch.Http.shutdown() in case of cascading Http calls

Tags: scala, future, scala-dispatch

At [Where to put dispatch.Http.shutdown()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722777/where-to-put-dispatch-http-shutdown) I asked where to place the call to `dispatch.Http.shutdown()` if there are `n` independent Http calls. Those `n` independent calls, however, are all on the same "level".

How about *cascading Http calls*, whereas `outer1` and `outer2` are independent of each other (like in my former question), the inner calls, however, depend on the result of the respective outer call.

```
val outer1 = dispatch.Http(... request1 ...)
val outer2 = dispatch.Http(... request2 ...)

outer1 onComplete {
  case Success(h) =>
    /*inner11*/ dispatch.Http(... request11 based on `h` ...) onComplete { ... }
    /*inner12*/ dispatch.Http(... request12 based on `h` ...) onComplete { ... }
  case Failure(e) => logger.debug(s"Error: $e")
}
outer2 onComplete {
  case Success(j) => 
    /*inner21*/ dispatch.Http(... request21 based on `j` ...) onComplete { ... }
    /*inner22*/ dispatch.Http(... request22 based on `j` ...) onComplete { ... }
  case Failure(e) => logger.debug(s"Error: $e")
}

dispatch.Future.sequence(outer1 :: outer2 :: Nil) onComplete { 
  case _ => dispatch.Http.shutdown() // <<<<< too early
}
```

Thanks, /nm

Update 1: Thanks to Kevin Wright, things are getting more clear. In the following I try to clarify why I need this cascading futures and the onComplete on the nested ones. Let's assume I want to get a list of URLs of all accessible GitHub repositories for an authenticated user:

```
object Main extends App with Logging {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def logFailure[T](f: Future[T]) =
    f onFailure { case x => logger.debug("Error: " + x.toString) }

  // Personal access token 
  val pat = "..."
  // GitHub API
  val github: Req = host("api.github.com").secure 
  // Http executor
  //val http = Http()

  // User profile of authenticated user
  val ur: Req = github / "user" <:< Map("Authorization" -> s"token $pat")

  // Retrieve *all* accessible repositories for authenticated user 
  Http(ur OK as.json4s.Json) flatMap { u =>
    // organizations' repos
    val inner1 = (u \ "organizations_url").toOption collect { case JString(org) =>
      Http(url(org) OK as.json4s.Json) flatMap { o =>
        (o \ "repos_url").toOption collect { case JString(rep) => 
          Http(url(rep) OK as.json4s.Json) map { _ \ "html_url" }
        }
      }
    }
    // user's repos
    val inner2 = (u \ "repos_url").toOption collect { case JString(usr) => 
      Http(url(usr) OK as.json4s.Json) map { _ \ "html_url" }
    }

    ???
  }
}
```

Then as soon as I have retrieved all the URLs I want to spawn a `git clone` process for each.

Unfortunately `inner1` does not yet type check. And still, if `inner1: Option[Future[JValue]]` and `inner2: Option[Future[JValue]]`, then `Future.sequence(inner1 :: inner2 :: Nil)` does not type check.

Answer (score 0):

You'd find things easier if you separated the success and failure paths.

```
import dispatch.Future

def logFailure[T](f: Future[T]) =
  f onFailure { case x => logger.debug("Error: " + x.toString) }

val outer1 = dispatch.Http(... request1 ...) flatMap { h =>
  val in1 = dispatch.Http(... request11 based on `h` ...)
  val in2 = dispatch.Http(... request12 based on `h` ...)
  in1 onComplete { ... }
  in2 onComplete { ... }
  Future.sequence(in1:: in2 :: Nil)            
}

val outer2 = dispatch.Http(... request2 ...) flatMap { j =>
  val in1 = dispatch.Http(... request21 based on `j` ...)
  val in2 = dispatch.Http(... request22 based on `j` ...)
  in1 onComplete { ... }
  in2 onComplete { ... }
  Future.sequence(in1:: in2 :: Nil)            
}

logFailure(outer1)
logFailure(outer2)

Future.sequence(outer1 :: outer2 :: Nil) onComplete { 
  case _ => dispatch.Http.shutdown() // <<<<< too early
}
```

If not for the `onComplete` of those nested operations, it could almost certainly be done far more and with less duplication using a couple of comprehensions.  As it is, I have no idea what you want to do inside of them.

Comment: Thanks @KevinWright! This helped. In my recent post update, I tried to clarify what I want to do. The problem I have now are the `Option`s. Maybe you have a second...